# issues with Docker on wsl (ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: python, django, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-build

An attempt to build a docker image fails on `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` step with the following error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/asgiref/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/asgiref/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/asgiref/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/asgiref/`
```

for some reason, `asgiref==3.5.2` doesn't want to install. What could be the reason for this?

System used:

- OS: Windows 11
- WSL 2 with Ubuntu 22.04 on board
- Docker version 20.10.19, build d85ef84
- Dockerfile contents:

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.10.6-slim-bullseye

# Set enviroment variables

ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory

WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy project

COPY . .
```

- requirements.txt contents:

```
asgiref==3.5.2
Django==4.1.2
sqlparse==0.4.3
```

Comment: You're getting a timeout error trying to connect to `pypi.org`. Could it be firewall related perhaps? Is this at work where you may have network security policies in place?

Comment: You could also try increasing the timeout by using something like `--default-timeout=100` when running `pip`.

Comment: @michjnich thanks for edits and your comments. For some reason, now it shows the following: 

```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement asgiref==3.5.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for asgiref==3.5.2```

Comment: @michjnich which is absurd, the Python and PIP versions are the same as used inside virtual environment and django4 along with asgiref installed perfectly fine there. Not sure what the issue is....

Comment: This is when running `docker build .` ? I copied your 2 files into an empty project and it works fine for me. If it's locally you're having issues just make sure you're on the right versions ... `python --version` - asgiref 3.5.2 needs 3.7 and above.

Comment: @michjnich yep, this is when I run `docker build . `. The python version I use is 3.10.6, so everything should be fine. Did you try this under WSL?

Comment: Ran it in docker under wsl2 and it worked fine. Interesting answer below though - curious to see if it works for you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the main issue was that I installed docker right from my WSL2 ubuntu distro using instructions for Linux and not with the help of official Windows installer, which seamlessly integrates with WSL2. Reinstalled and now network works as intended. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today. So, you can fix this issue with a `--network host` in your Docker build line.

The reason for this is issue is an MTU mismatch of your network interfaces. If you open the base image from your Dockerfile in interactive mode: `sudo docker run -it {your base image repo} /bin/bash`, and run `ip a`, then do the same on your host OS, you will probably find that they are different. This means that the Docker bridge is dropping packets / failing transmission. If you want bridge networking to work as opposed to host, create a file on your host OS at `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with the contents

```
{
    "mtu": whatever_your_host_os_MTU_is
}
```

and then run `sudo systemctl restart docker`, this should probably fix your bridge networking.

EDIT: I should add that this is only the case (most likely) if you have internet connectivity from your container (i.e. apt/yum works but something else like pip breaks). If you cannot pull anything, you probably have a DNS/firewall issue.

Comment: Yes! This was actually it, adding `--network host` to the command fixed the issue. Thanks a ton!

Comment: no prob, and yeah if you want to use bridge networking (host networking can be a pain since it maps docker container ports directly to your host OS ports, so can cause conflicts), you'll have to do the steps above

Comment: tried adding  daemon.json and setting MTU, but this didn't have any effect after docker daemon restart, unfortunately( any other ideas how to resolve this? Even if run a docker container and then run 'apt update', I get 'Temporary failure resolving 'deb.debian.org''.